# Regular Expression to validate email

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace read_test
{
    class StringCheck
    {
        static void Main(String [] args)
        {
            string email = "email@email.com";

        string regEx = @"\w+\.?\w+\@{1}\w+\.{1}\w+";

        Match aMatch;
        aMatch = Regex.Match(email, regEx);

        if (aMatch.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("Successfull.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Successfull");

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

}

tried writing a regular expression to check if the email id entered is valid. Is this right? Or is there a better way

Comment: `{1}` qualifiers are redundant. You allow only one dot in login, which is wrong. TLD should be at least 2 symbols. [Here is the RFC-compliant Regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), which shows you that there are plenty of requirements. And after all, it's better to listen to those guys, who said that you don't need the Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, you dont really need a regex

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the best and easiest way to proof the format.

Comment: Thank you for this, I learnt something new. I was told to write a regular expression, that is why I needed to know if the code is correct? and if there is a better way to use regular expression.